# File handling with PHP over local network

Tags: php, file-permissions, fopen

Hi I am using `fopen` php function to maintain log. I can write to the file within my own computer. But how to make PHP able to write file over the local network. Other computer in the network access my computer PHP application through IP but fails with permission when writing to the log file. My code is:

```
function hotellog($txt) {
   date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kathmandu");
   $newfile = '\\localhost\gandaki/wp-content/hotel_log.json';
   if (file_exists($newfile)) {
      $myfile = fopen($newfile, "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
      $txt = date("Y-m-d h:i:s") . "\r\t\t" . $txt . "\n\n\n";
      fwrite($myfile, $txt);

      fclose($myfile);
   } else {
      $myfile = fopen($newfile, 'w') or die("Can't create file");
      $txt = date("Y-m-d h:i:s") . "\r\t\t" . $txt . "\n\n\n";
      fwrite($myfile, $txt);

      fclose($myfile);
  }
}
```

Other computers over networks get the error as 'permission denied'.

Comment: Assuming you're not using `localhost` on those? Set the permissions properly then.

Comment: I have read write permission from file system but also its say permission denied.

Comment: And the permissions on the share? For the specific user account?

Comment: For everyone there is read and execute permission. How to give write permission also.

Answer (score 0):

PHP can not (well, should not) be able to write files over the network onto your computer under normal circumstances.  You would be better off writing the log file on your local computer and then scripting a file transfer via sftp, or something similar, from your local computer to the remote one.